# Graylog check if time is plausible

Tags: graylog3

Something like this:
timestamp > now -  and timestamp < now + 
So if the message is not in the future or too much in the past.

I tried to do this with pipelines, but I couldn't get a timestamp and add there a few seconds and couldn't check the time against the timestamp in the message. The idea with pipelines was to check and write a new field if the time isn't right and create a alarm that searches for this field

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Create an alert in Graylog with timestamp interval ?

Comment: Just create a alert when time from the message is incorrect for example, when the message is from the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pipeline rule, which insert new field if timestamp is lower or higher than 1 hour from server's time:

```
rule "check wrong timestamp"
when
    parse_date(value: to_string($message.timestamp), pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") - seconds(3600) > now() || 
    parse_date(value: to_string($message.timestamp), pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") + seconds(3600) < now()
then
  //set_field("timestamp", now()); // uncomment if want to fix timestamp
  set_field("timestamp_problem", "true");
end
```